# How to trigger click event after another click

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a wordpress mobile navigation where all item collapse (which has 2nd level) when i open the menu .I need to open the about-us section when the menu  open. So I try this code but no luck . the `.w-nav-control` is the menu controller class. Please help me what I'm doing wrong?

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(document).on('click', '.w-nav-control', function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.autoopen').find('span.w-nav-arrow').trigger('click');
        }, 800);
   });
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but I need to warn you that triggering a click is a bad practice and you should not use it (https://davidwalsh.name/dont-trigger-real-event-names). At least, you should better use a custom event like 'menu-open' or 'menu-close', for instance, and make the concerned node listen to this event.

Comment: Instead of doing the trigger why don't you show the dropdown menu directly.

Comment: There is no option to show it directly

Comment: So there is no solution ? for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to troubleshoot this without a jsfiddle, but here's how I'd approach the problem.  You have essentially two points of failure for your code: the click capture and the click trigger.  First, I'd make sure the click event is being triggered with this code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(document).on('click', '.w-nav-control', function(event) { 
     event.preventDefault(); 
     alert('clicked');
   });
});
```

If that works, you know the problem lies in your click trigger code.  Perhaps try a more specific selector:

```
$('#menu-item-5897').find('span.w-nav-arrow').trigger('click');
```

or perhaps:

```
$('#menu-item-5897 > .w-nav-anchor > .w-nav-arrow').trigger('click');
```

or maybe:

```
$('.autoopen > .w-nav-anchor > .w-nav-arrow').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks The menu selector `$('#menu-item-5897 > .w-nav-anchor > .w-nav-arrow').trigger('click');` is the correct . and it works but I use the `setTimeout(function()` for looks more professional